# Trying to start statsD via chef

Tags: node.js, chef-infra, statsd

I'm trying to start statsD on ubuntu but I'm running into problems.

If I start it, it works but blocks chef from continuing but it works and shows up in graphite.

If however I start it like this (or using other methods to get it start in the background):

`(/usr/bin/node /opt/statsd/stats.js /opt/statsd/localConfig.js) &`

it doesn't block chef but nothing shows up in graphite, however I know it's still running because

`ps aux | grep stat`

shows the command as running (not including the grep command).

I've tried to do it using forever.js but npm just reports as having `failed to fetch from registry: forever`

Edit:

Ok, well I managed to get it to start using

`nohup /usr/bin/node /opt/statsd/stats.js /opt/statsd/localConfig.js`

This starts statsD (good) and it doesn't block chef (also good) but it now refuses to stop running when I try

`sudo killall -r stat`

In hindsight it's becuase nohup stops it from receiving the kill signal.

So the question becomes how can I get it to run in the background using nohup (or somthing like it) but still be able to stop statsD so it can be restarted (for any potential change in config).

EDIT:

Ok, by changing the start command to:

`nohup /usr/bin/node /opt/statsd/stats.js /opt/statsd/localConfig.js >> /var/log/statsd.log 2>&1& \n  echo $! /opt/statsd/statds.pid`

I was able to store the pid and then using

`` kill -9 `/opt/statsd/statsd.pid` ``

I was able to kill the process however it still leaves `rcp.statd -L` running which has a separate pid

Comment: Did you had a look at [this cookbook](https://github.com/librato/statsd-cookbook) it has upstart scripts for running statsd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well I managed to create a bash command that will find and kill any process with the word `stat` in it; which for me works fine as only statd related process has `stat` in it.

So, the command to start statD is:

`nohup /usr/bin/node /opt/statsd/stats.js /opt/statsd/localConfig.js >> /var/log/statsd.log 2>&1&`

A bit long winded but I'm using absolute paths.

The command to stop is:

`ps aux | awk '/stat/ {print $2}' | xargs kill -9`

Pretty simple and even better I don't need to do the whole "store the pid in a txt file" to kill statsd when I need to restart.

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted if it solved your issue, even though you wrote it yourself. This serves as a clear statement to other users that that's the accepted solution.

Comment: ... you realise that you can't mark an answer to your own question as accepted for 2 days right?

Comment: I was not aware of that. Couldn't find any documentation to that either. If you have a link, I'd be grateful.
In any case, if that's so then please mark it as accepted in a couple of days. :)

Comment: To be honest, whether it's documented or not, I don't know; I only know that because the website errors when you try to accept an answer before that time limit is up, at the moment it's at 22-hours before I can accept.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is probably to have Chef install an init script and let your init daemon handle all the statsd daemon management. That way you can use Chef's `service` resource to manage the instance.

StatsD includes an [example init script](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/debian/statsd.init) in the Debian resources which you can use or adapt to your needs.